# Tweepy Cursor get tweets from users with specific string in their username

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="football",lang="en").items(50):
```

I'm trying to get tweets from user's with specific text in their username. Then also find a tweet that has specific text in. I've tried multiple times but doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The Twitter search API that you are calling does not support finding users by username.

Comment: what can I use then @AndyPiper

Answer (score 0):

Credentials are stored in a file, but you can change the code to however you prefer.
This loops through usernames and just prints the tweet count but you can, again, modify as necessary to process the tweets as you wish

```
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Cursor
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from pprint import pprint
import twitter_credentials
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# # # # TWITTER CLIENT # # # #
class TwitterClient():
    def __init__(self, twitter_user=None):
        self.auth = TwitterAuthenticator().authenticate_twitter_app()
        self.twitter_client = API(self.auth)

        self.twitter_user = twitter_user

#-------------------------------get tweets------------------------------------------
    def get_user_timeline_tweets(self, num_tweets=20, repbool=False, rtsbool=True):
        tweets = []
        # name of tweepy api reference is 'user_timeline'

        for tweet in Cursor(self.twitter_client.user_timeline, id=self.twitter_user, tweet_mode='extended', include_entities=True, exclude_replies=repbool, include_rts=rtsbool).items(num_tweets):
            tweets.append(tweet)
            # print(tweet._json)
        return tweets
#-------------------------------get tweets------------------------------------------


# # # # TWITTER AUTHENTICATER # # # #
class TwitterAuthenticator():

    def authenticate_twitter_app(self):
        auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_KEY, twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN, twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
        return auth

num_tweets = 200
user_list = ['TwitterSupport', 'TwitterMovies']
for user_handle in user_list:
# print(user_handle)
    twitter_client = TwitterClient(user_handle)
    tweets = twitter_client.get_user_timeline_tweets(num_tweets)
    print(len(tweets))
```